# pandas get_level_values behaives unexpectedly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index in my dataframe like this:

```
x = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['2014.12.31', 'd', 'e', '2015.12.31']],
labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]],
names=['proj', 0])
x.get_level_values(0)
x.get_level_values(1)
```

I expect the `get_level_values(0)` and `get_level_values(1)` to give me different results. But they don't. Is this a bug?

However, `x.get_level_values('proj')` and `x.get_level_values(0)` give me the results I expect. Why? Can someone please explain that? Thanks.

Comment: It's because your names=['proj', **0**]. If the name for the 2nd level of the index was anything other than **0** it would work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two index levels, and you can get them either by name or by integer index. The index level at integer index `0` has name `proj`, a string. The index level at integer index `1` has name `0`, an integer.

When you call `get_level_values(level)`, `pandas` searches the index level by name first. So in your situation, calling `get_level_values(0)` resolves to the second level with the name `0` and `get_level_values(1)` resolves to the same level, but in this case by integer index `1`.

Comment: The moral of the story is use descriptive index level names instead of integers. Pandas permits lots of ambiguity, it pays to make sure you can avoid it where possible.